# When in debug mode, how to get back to controller class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When in debug mode, and when I press 'n', after a while it goes into the internals of rails, how do I jump back to my controller class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `finish` to complete the stack frame you're in (in the internals of Rails). You may need to do this several times before you are back where you want to be.

For the definitive guide (or should I say, manual), see: http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html.